# Changing primary key from IDENTITY to being persisted Computed column using COALESCE

Tags: sql-server, identity, computed-column

In an attempt to decouple an application from our monolithic database, we've tried to change INT IDENTITY columns of various tables to be a PERSISTED computed column that uses COALESCE. Basically, we need the decoupled application an ability to still update the database for common data shared across many applications while still allowing existing applications to create data in these tables without the need for code or procedure modification.

So essentially, we've moved from a column definition of;

```
PkId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
```

to;

```
PkId AS AS COALESCE(old_id, external_id, new_id) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
old_id INT NULL, -- Values here are from existing records of PkId before table change
external_id INT NULL,
new_id INT IDENTITY(2000000,1) NOT NULL
```

In all cases the PkId is also a PRIMARY KEY and in all but one case, it is CLUSTERED. All tables have the same foreign keys and indexes as before. In essence, the new format allows the PkId to be supplied by the decoupled application (as external_id), but also allows the PkId to be the IDENTITY column value therefore allowing existing code that relies on the IDENTITY column  through use of SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY to work as it used to.

The problem we've had is that we've come across a couple of queries that used to run in an acceptable time to now blow out completely. The generated query plans used by these queries is nothing like what it used to be before.

Given the new column is a PRIMARY KEY, the same data type as before, and PERSISTED, I would have expected queries and query plans to behave the same as they did before. Should the COMPUTED PERSISTED INT PkId essentially behave the same way as an explicit INT definition in terms of how SQL Server will produce the execution plan? Are there other likely issues with this approach that you can see?

The purpose of this change was supposed to allow us to change the table definition without the need to modify existing procedures and code. Given these issues, I don't feel like we can go with this approach.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48269/discussion-on-question-by-mr-moose-changing-primary-key-from-identity-to-being-p).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**FIRST**

You probably don't need all three columns: `old_id`, `external_id`, `new_id`. The `new_id` column, being an `IDENTITY`, will have a new value generated for each row, even when you insert into `external_id`. But, between `old_id` and `external_id`, those are pretty much mutually exclusive: either there is already an `old_id` value *or* that column, in the current conception, will just be `NULL` if using `external_id` or `new_id`. Since you won't be adding a new "external" id to a row that already exists (i.e. one that has an `old_id` value), and there won't be any new values coming in for `old_id`, then there can be one column that is used for both purposes.

So, get rid of the `external_id` column and rename `old_id` to be something like `old_or_external_id` or whatever. This shouldn't require any real changes to anything, yet reduces some of the complication. At most you might need to call the column `external_id`, even if it contains "old" values, if app code is already written to insert into `external_id`.

That reduces the new structure to be just:

```
PkId AS AS COALESCE(old_or_external_id, new_id, -1) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
old_or_external_id INT NULL, -- values from existing record OR passed in from app
new_id INT IDENTITY(2000000, 1) NOT NULL
```

Now you have only added 8 bytes per row instead of 12 bytes (assuming that you aren't using the `SPARSE` option or Data Compression). And you didn't need to change any code, T-SQL or App code.

**SECOND**

Continuing down this path of simplification, let's look at what we have left:

- The `old_or_external_id` column either has values already, or will be given a new value from the app, or will be left as `NULL`.
- The `new_id` will always have a new value generated, but that value will only be used if the `old_or_external_id` column is `NULL`.

There is never a time when you would need values in both `old_or_external_id` and `new_id`. Yes, there will be times when both columns have values due to `new_id` being an `IDENTITY`, but those `new_id` values are ignored. Again, these two fields are mutually exclusive. So what now?

Now we can look into why we needed the `external_id` in the first place. Considering that it is possible to insert into an `IDENTITY` column using `SET IDENTITY_INSERT {table_name} ON;`, you could get away with making no schema changes at all, and only modify your app code to wrap the `INSERT` statements / operations in `SET IDENTITY_INSERT {table_name} ON;` and `SET IDENTITY_INSERT {table_name} OFF;` statements. You then need to determine what starting range to reset the `IDENTITY` column to (for newly generated values) as it will need to be well above the values that the App code will be inserting since inserting a higher value will cause the next auto-generated value to be greater than the current MAX value. But you can always insert a value that is below the [IDENT_CURRENT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx) value.

Combining the `old_or_external_id` and `new_id` columns also does not increase the chances of running into an overlapping value situation between auto-generated values and app-generated values since the intention of having the 2, or even 3, columns is to combine them into a Primary Key value, and those are always unique values.

In this approach, you just need to:

- Leave tables as being:

  ```
  PkId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
  ```

  This adds 0 bytes to each row, instead of 8, or even 12.
- Determine the starting range for app-generated values. These will be greater than the current MAX value in each table, but less than what will become the minimum value for the auto-generated values.
- Determine what value the auto-generated range should start at. There should be plenty of room between the current MAX value *and* plenty of room to grow, knowing at the upper limit is just over 2.14 billion. You can then set this new minimum seed value via [DBCC CHECKIDENT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx).
- Wrap app code INSERTs in `SET IDENTITY_INSERT {table_name} ON;` and `SET IDENTITY_INSERT {table_name} OFF;` statements.

**SECOND, Part B**

A variation on the approach noted directly above would be to have the App code insert values starting with -1 and going *down* from there. This leaves the `IDENTITY` values as being the only ones going *up*. The benefit here is that you not only don't complicate the schema, you also don't need to worry about running into overlapping IDs (if the app-generated values run into the new auto-generated range). This is only an option if you aren't already using negative ID values (and it seems pretty rare for people to use negative values on auto-generated columns so this should be a likely posibility in most situations).

In this approach, you just need to:

- Leave tables as being:

  ```
  PkId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
  ```

  This adds 0 bytes to each row, instead of 8, or even 12.
- The starting range for app-generated values will be `-1`.
- Wrap app code INSERTs in `SET IDENTITY_INSERT {table_name} ON;` and `SET IDENTITY_INSERT {table_name} OFF;` statements.

Here you still need to do the `IDENTITY_INSERT`, but: you don't add any new columns, don't need to "reseed" any `IDENTITY` columns, and have no future risk of overlaps.

**SECOND, Part 3**

One last variation of this approach would be to possibly swap out the `IDENTITY` columns and instead use [Sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx). The reason to take this approach is to be able to have the app code insert values that are: positive, above the auto-generated range (not below), and no need for `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON / OFF`.

In this approach, you just need to:

- Create Sequences using [CREATE SEQUENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)
- Copy the `IDENTITY` column to a new column that doesn't have the `IDENTITY` property, but does have a `DEFAULT` Constraint using the [NEXT VALUE FOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx) function:

  ```
  PkId INT PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT [DF_TableName_NextID] DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR...)
  ```

  This adds 0 bytes to each row, instead of 8, or even 12.
- The starting range for app-generated values will well above what you think the auto-generated values will approach.
- Wrap app code INSERTs in `SET IDENTITY_INSERT {table_name} ON;` and `SET IDENTITY_INSERT {table_name} OFF;` statements.

*HOWEVER*, due to the requirement that code with either `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or `@@IDENTITY` still functions properly, switching to Sequences is not currently an option as it appears that there is no equivalent of those functions for Sequences :-(. Sad!

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. You raise a few points that were discussed here internally. Unfortunately, some of these won't work for us for a couple of reasons. Our database is quite old and somewhat brittle and runs under 2005 compatibility mode so SEQUENCES are out. Our app data push occurs via a data load tool that obtains new records from service broker queues and pushes them via multiple threads. IDENTITY_INSERT can only be used for one table per session, and the current thinking is our architecture can't cater for that without significant change. I'm testing your fist suggestion now.

Comment: @MrMoose Yeah, I updated my answer to include more info about Sequences at the end. It wouldn't work in your situation anyway. And I was wondering about potential concurrency issues with `IDENTITY_INSERT`, but haven't tested it. Not sure option #1 is going to solve your overall issue, it was just an observation to reduce needless complexity. Still, if you have multiple threads inserting new "external" IDs, how do you guarantee that they are unique?

Comment: @MrMoose Actually, regarding "_IDENTITY_INSERT can only be used for one table per session_", what exactly is the issue here? 1) you can only insert into one table at a time, so you turn it off for TableA before inserting into TableB, and 2) I just tested and contrary to what I had thought, there are no concurrency issues -- I was able to have `IDENTITY_INSERT ON` for the same table in two sessions and was inserting into both with no problems.

Comment: As you suggested, change 1 made little difference. The ID we will use will be allocated outside of the current database and used to relate records. It may well be that my understanding of sessions isn't quite right so IDENTITY_INSERT might work. It will take a little time for me to investigate that though, so I won't be able to report back for a little while. Thanks again for the input. It is much appreciated.

Comment: @MrMoose That's fine. But as far as I can tell, there is no reason that `IDENTITY_INSERT` would pose a problem. Definitely need to test it before ruling it out.

Comment: I think your suggestion of using IDENTITY_INSERT (with a high seed value for existing apps) will work well. Aaron Bertrand provided an answer [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/68063/9936) with a good little example on testing it with concurrency. We've modified our data load tool to be able to handle tables that need to specify identity values and we'll get onto some further testing in the coming weeks.